# Embedded Linux - Updating Multiple Widgets with Multiple controls and with Multiple Timers in QT

Tags: performance, qt4

As i am a newbie to QT, I am having some sort problems in developing the QT application.
My application consists of Multiple Widgets, where each widget consists of multiple controls like text edit, push buttons, table views etc., where all the controls will be updated using multiple timers with diff intervals. The updating of controls data is getting through TCP/IP ethernet communication.

Everything is Working perfect except the GUI is very slow. Means the widgets loading very slow whenever i require to show the widget and also the updating the text edits, Q labels and Table view controls using timers.

So what could be the problem ?

My mainwindow.ui consists of 20 Widgets each of them having 20+ controls each of them will be updated using timers intervals.

Comment: As you're using embeded linux I need to know what architecture do you use? Does your architecture has FPU? Are you using CSS in your app? There are many factors that make ui slow on embeded platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Usually software engineers do not discuss what could be a performance problem before having a profiling report. I suggest to use [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/), which is measuring performance of the whole Linux system. [OProfile reports](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/) show where CPU time was spent: process, library, function/method. With that kind of information it's really easy to identify a performance bottleneck and depending on what it is to change existing application to solve performance problems.

Initialize OProfile (kernel with OProfile support must be installed):

```
export KREXP=dpkg -L kernel-debug | grep "vmlinux-2.6"
opcontrol --init
opcontrol --vmlinux=$KREXP --separate=kernel
```

Run OProfile:

```
opcontrol --stop; opcontrol --reset; opcontrol --start;
```

Run applications and then stop OProfile:

```
opcontrol --stop
```

Basic OProfile reports:

```
opreport
```

or

```
opreport path_to_binary
```

Comment: i am unable to install the oprofile on my ubuntu system. i tried manually to install it. It was installed but i cant Run Oprofile.

Comment: Installing oprofile on ubuntu is as easy as "sudo apt-get install oprofile".